# Android "Unfortunately has stopped" Error

Tags: android

I am new to android programming. I just want to make custom camera in android. To make this, i used this website (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html)
Although i followed steps in website, i got an error "unfortunately yourapplication has stopped". I searched all questions about "Unfortunately has stopped" and i read the answers in here. But they didn't help me. Please help me!

Here is my cameraActivity code:

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity {

protected static final String TAG = null;
protected static final String MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = ".jpeg";
private static Camera mCamera;
private CameraPreview mPreview;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

    // Create an instance of Camera
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();

    // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById (R.id.camera_preview);
    preview.addView(mPreview);


    final PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
            if (pictureFile == null){
                Throwable e = null;
                Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: " +
                    e.getMessage());
                return;
            }

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        private File getOutputMediaFile(String mediaTypeImage) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    };

Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(id.button_capture);
captureButton.setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // get an image from the camera
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
        }});}

public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}}
```

When i clicked error in logcat, it showed me this

```
"mcamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);"
```

in this code:

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {


private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Camera mcamera;

public CameraPreview(Context context,Camera camera){
    super(context);
    mcamera=camera;
    mHolder=getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
    try {
        mcamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mcamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

In LogCat

```
E/AndroidRuntime(1071): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 E/AndroidRuntime(1071): java.lang.NullPointerException
 E/AndroidRuntime(1071):    at com.example.ntry.CameraPreview.surfaceCreated(CameraPreview.java:32)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1071):    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:569)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1071):    at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:86)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1071):    at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:174)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1071):    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:680)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1071):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1842)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1071):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1071):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1071):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1071):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1071):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1071):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1071):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1071):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1071):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1071):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1071):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1071):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1071):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1071):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1071):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What's on line 32 CameraPreview?

Comment: @Raghunandan on line 32--> "mcamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);"

Comment: If you want good camera code example look at this project done by college students https://github.com/ProjPossibility/2014-CSUN-Cam4Blind

Answer (score 0):

If it happens when your application starts first time then your camera object is Null or your holder is Null

But if it happens when you navigate second time to your camera view then your camera is reserved with the previous view and not accessible for the second time then you have to release camera on pausing your view or destroying your view

hope it will help

Comment: I don't understand. You mean there is a problem in Camera c=null ?

Comment: are you getting this crash from the very first time application rns?

Comment: Yes i got crash for the first time my application runs.

Answer (score 0):

From here it looks like `getCameraInstance` is returning null. Is `Camera.open()` raising an exception?

Comment: No there is no an exception about Camera.open().

Comment: Your `mcamera` appears to be null, and this is one way it can happen looking at your code. Another is that `.open()` is returning null without raising an NPE.

Comment: Sigh, you tell us (but don't really, I'm speaking figuratively). Make a `null` check for defence. Figure out why and how `.open()` can return null.

Comment: You mean something like that "if(c!=null) do this" ?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know.. If I knew, i didn't ask question something like that. I don't ask you to teach me, but maybe you can make it clear for me..